# session.run error when implement a pairwise cnn with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am very new to tensorflow. Now I am implementing a pairwise cnn model. While I got the error:

> tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow.StatusNotOK: Not found:
>   FeedInputs: unable to find feed output Placeholder:0

The error is attributed to the code:

```py
_,train_loss,train_feature1,train_feature2=sess.run([model.train_op,model.cost,model.feature1,model.feature2],feed)
```

Specifically in `sess.run` function, `feed` is a dictionary containing input data and corresponding labels. `feature1` and `feature2` are the output of the same neural networks and finally I would like to compare `feature1` and `feature2`.

The gist codes are:

```py
with self.graph.device('/gpu:1'):
     self.inputs1=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[self.batchSize,self.inputH,self.inputW,hp.channel])
     self.inputs2=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[self.batchSize,self.inputH,self.inputW,hp.channel])

     self.labels=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[self.batchSize])

     self.feature1=forward(self.inputs1)
     self.feature2=forward(self.inputs2)

     self.cost=tf.reduce_sum( tf.mul( -1.0*self.labels, tf.sub( self.feature1,self.feature2 ) ) )

     self.tvars=tf.trainable_variables()
     grads=tf.gradients(self.cost,self.tvars)
     optimizer=tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate=self.learning_rate,momentum=self.momentum)
     self.train_op=optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads,self.tvars))
```

Here I create three placeholders, and do some operations like `train_op`. Forward is the neural networks used in my implementation. Then in the training part, I load text data and labels with `data_loader.next_batch()`, finally run the optimization operation with `sess.run()`. The codes is available below.

```py
for b in xrange(data_loader.batch_num):
    pbar.update(int((b/data_loader.batch_num)*100) )
    time.sleep(0.01)
    maps1,maps2,labels=data_loader.next_batch()
    feed={model.labels:labels,model.inputs1:maps1,model.inputs2:maps2}
    _,train_loss,train_feature1,train_feature2=sess.run([model.train_op,model.cost,model.feature1,model.feature2],feed)
```

**NEW ERROR**

I tried to change the maps1 as Tensors instead of numpy ndarray, the error above disappeared. Unfortunately new errors raised.

> File "Train.py", line 55, in train      _,train_loss,train_feature1,train_feature2=sess.run([model.train_op,model.cost,model.feature1,model.feature2],feed)
>         File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py",
>   line 334, in run
>           np_val = np.array(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_t.dtype.as_numpy_dtype)
>       ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: Niceties for future questions: It's better to include formatted text rather than screenshots of text, and you don't include any of the problematic code.

Comment: In any case: I believe that means you are creating a `tf.placeholder` and not giving a value for the placeholder in your call to `sess.run`.  Can you include the code (maybe as a gist if it's too large) so that we can see what is going on?

Comment: Thanks for your information, I have changed my question and it seems more formal. I will check whether the real data can be delivered to placeholder.

Comment: That looks reasonable, so I'm still not sure what's going on.  Can you give the full error message (not just the last line), the names of the tensors you're feeding (`self.input1.name`, etc.), and the types of the data you're feeding (`type(map1)`, etc.)?

Comment: hi @GeoffreyIrving, thanks for your feedback. The self.input1.name is Placeholder:0. Regarding type(maps1), I tried to change it as Tensor then new errors appeared as I said above.The input to sess.run should be a real numpy ndarray or a Tensor?

Comment: As I known now, the error might be attributed to the type of placeholder (int32) and input data(float32) is different. Although I announced that the placeholder should be float or tf.float32, it does not work.